# What is a "resolver" when deploying to maven repositories?

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory

We're trying to setup Gradle to publish artifacts to Artifactory. There are two sets of credentials that can be configured, a "deployer" and "resolver". The deployer seems fairly obvious, as the target repository is read-only, a set of credentials are necessary to authenticate for deployment.

However, what is this "resolver" in the context of maven repositories. We are already using Gradle's dependency management, so project dependencies are already getting resolved via the repositories we have configured using Gradle.

So what's the point of this second "resolver" configuration, and why would it need credentials?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you show the code where you encounter a "deployer" and a "resolver"?

Comment: Take a look at the Artifactory plugins: http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin and https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin  Maybe resolver repositories are specific to artifactory, but it makes it sound like a Maven concept.

Comment: OK. You didn’t say you were using Artifactory's Gradle plugin.

Comment: I didn't know it was specific to the Gradle Artifactory Plugin. I'm still new to Maven concepts, and thought it was specific to Maven in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the [Gradle Artifactory Plugin](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin), then it allows you to set optional user/pass for a repository that requires authenticated read access (can be set in Artifactory using [permission targets](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions)).

A maven (or ivy, if configured) repository with these credentials will be added to your project by the plugin behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is needed e.g. if you use your own enterprise repository (like Nexus or Artifactory) and you even need credentials to read that repositories (which may be the case in companies).